Flexbox complex design
I’m working on a React project. I want to create a flex layout but I’m struggling to achieve the design I’m looking for.
Can you please tell me how would you do it? Or maybe recommend any other approach to it?
The goal layout:
Layout image
This is my code so far:
HTML
<div className="main">
        <div className="secondRow">
            <div className="profilePicContainer">
                <img
                    src={profile}
                    alt="profilePic"
                    className="profilePic"
                />
                <div className="profilePicBackground"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="welcomeContainer">
                <h1>Hola! Soy Oscar Garza</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="thirdRow">
            <div className="description">
                <p>Desarrollador web y móvil con experiencia en…</p>
            </div>
            <img
                src={coding}
                alt="coding gif"
                className="coding"
            />
        </div>
    </div>

CSS
@import '../../assets/styles.css';

.secondRow {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
 }

 .profilePicContainer {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
 }

 .profilePicBackground {
     background-color: var(--red);
     border-radius: 16px;
     width: 170px;
     height: 150px;
     margin-top: 100px;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }

 .profilePic {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 10;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .welcomeContainer {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: orange;
     border-radius: 16px;
 }

 .thirdRow {
     flex: 1;
 }


Frsnkly, flexbox is not an optimal option for such a proposed layout. CSS Grid might give better options.
